# How to add Button+ScrollView in Swift together?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uibutton, scrollview

### I would like to create a level menu in swift.

I have a ScrollView and an image inside the ScrollView .

---

I would like to add a button which stays at the same place when the ScrollView scrolls. 
If I put the button on the same level as the Scrollerview, it would work but the image inside the 
 ScrollView covers the button. If i put the button inside, it starts to move as i scroll.

How can i scroll the image and leave the button at the same place?

Comment: Let the button on top of the image view...?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the button on the same level as the ScrollView but above in the element list.

[image]